# CollectionView header content under status bar

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Here's a collection view constrained to top, left, right, and bottom of the superview with **safe area layout guide** enabled:

[image]

I want my collection view header to be shown **under** the status bar. I've achieved this for iPhone 4 - 8+ screen dimensions by unchecking **Safe Area Layout Guide** in the size inspector for the controller's main `view`, and adding the following code:

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

This looks great for *non iPhone X* view sizes:

[image]

However, for the iPhone X, this leads to the following output:

[image]

The iPhone X has its own dimensions for the status bar. Adjusting the top inset further **does** work, but will over-offset the other device sizes. I am wondering if there's an more elegant way to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
collectionView.contentInset.top = -UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Answer (score 8):

The previous solutions work, but this might be the easiest one:

`collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: Indeed, but this will cause the bottom to go under the bottom safe area. This is not something that you might want.

Answer (score 3):

This will do

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: this must be marked as accepted answer, you are my hero!

Answer (score 2):

You should use safeAreaInsets for iphone X

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if let top = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top {
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -top, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    collectionView.contentInset.top = -UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 constraints:

1) view - superview

[image]

2) view - safeArea

[image]