# CollectionViewCell scrolls to wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionView that is pinned to the to of the view (shown in 1st photo) and it has `isPagingEnabled = true`. I also hide the navigationBar.

When the cv loads for the very first time, the cell incorrectly displays underneath the device's top notch (shown in 2nd photo).

When I scroll/page the cell displays itself correctly behind the notch (3rd photo).

If I scroll/page back up to the 1st cell it positions itself correctly (3rd photo).  However if I then pull the cv down, the cell snaps back to the incorrect position (2nd photo).

I also notice when the cell is in the wrong position, if I tap it it scrolls itself to the correct position.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050752/4833705) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857162/4833705) and neither worked. I called `view.layoutIfNeeded()` and `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` in the functions.

**Why is the cell displaying itself incorrectly when the cv first loads and when I pull to refresh but when I page either up or down it displays correctly?**

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView  = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(HomeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: homeCell)

    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

    return collectionView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    setCollectionViewAnchors()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    let height = collectionView.frame.height

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func setCollectionViewAnchors() {

    let homeIndicatorHeight: CGFloat = 34 // https://stackoverflow.com/a/56639186/4833705

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -homeIndicatorHeight).isActive = true
}
```

1st photo, cv anchor, top is pinned to the very top of the view behind the notch.

[image]

2nd photo, cell displays incorrectly behind notch for very first time and when on the 1st cell, when pulling cv down it displays incorrectly.

[image]

3rd photo, cell displays correctly behind the notch when scrolling/paging

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055576/4833705).

I had to add this line to my collectionView:

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: Update I also had to add this line because some weird behavior occurred where cellForItem wasn't getting called after scrolling back to the same cell: **collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false**

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the `viewWillAppear()` method, like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: doesn't work on the iPhone with notch, thanks for trying

Comment: try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidAppear()` instead. sometimes it helps

Comment: doesn't work there either. It wouldn't work in either of those because the problems occurs even after the those methods run. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug with when resizing a UICollectionView, the cell position became incorrect.

> This helped display my cells correctly **layoutSubviews() + selectItem() + reloadData()**

```
func changeCollectionFrame() {
    myCollection.constant = self.view.frame.width
    self.myCollection.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.myCollection.layoutSubviews()
    self.myCollection.reloadData()

    // index - myIndexPath
    self.myCollection.selectItem(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    self.myCollection.reloadData()
}
```